# How to make div with variable width to fill rest of parent and make itself scrollable if neccessary

Tags: html, css

I have created this layout http://jsfiddle.net/6GVSu/ and the idea is to have centered container, which can have variable width, depending on its content. This is working just fine, but in this container I want to have header section which stays allways on top and the body container, which should fill the rest of the centered parent and show scrollbars if needed.

And now I am kind of stuck, I have tried to make this body container `absolute positioned` and stretch it within the parent, bud it will cancel its possibility to stretch the parent horizontaly.

And when I left it without positioning, it fills the rest of its parent as in fiddle, but it doesn't show the scrollbar eventually.

So please can someone give me some suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the height of the `<div class="body"></div>` & set its `overflow-y: scroll'
Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/6GVSu/3/ **updated**

```
.body
{
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: But then the body div wont fill the green parent and my user wont be using all possible space

Comment: Yeah, that's almost it, I only added `height:10%` to the header and `height:90%`to the body so the lowest part of body isn't missing and it is perfect :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set a height on the "body" class

```
.body
{
    overflow:auto;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Take off the height on the "innerPositionDiv" element

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6GVSu/2/)

Comment: Because I wanted the `.body div` to "grow" until it fills the parent and then show the scrollbar, so I can't set the height to some fixed value